# Can python's sched module run asynchronous tasks without blocking during a task execution?

Tags: python, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

I have a Module class, with an `invoke()` method, which may execute some IO-bound/wait.

I use `sched` to run multiple instances of said class at different intervals, in a way that may make a long-running call overlap with another task.

Can the `sched` module spawn different tasks and work with them in a non-blocking way, and if not, which module may do the job *for multiple repetitive concurrent tasks*?

I looked into `sched` but couldn't find any definitive answer.
I also looked into `asyncio`, which prompted me with two answers that don't seem to fit my needs, respectively [`while True` (which seems cumbersome)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54153453/10165294) and [Tasks (which doesn't appear to allow to run multiple methods concurrently)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37512537/10165294).

Comment: The Asyncio module is what you need.

Comment: I guessed as much, based on what I could find, but which structure should I follow to properly make recurrent concurrent scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study the code below, chapter 18 from Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho is an excellent resource on the asyncio module. Also, never forget the docs itself at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# spinner_asyncio.py

# credits: Example by Luciano Ramalho inspired by
# Michele Simionato's multiprocessing example in the python-list:
# https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-February/538048.html

import asyncio
import itertools
import sys


@asyncio.coroutine  # <1>
def spin(msg):  
    write, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush
    for char in itertools.cycle('|/-\\'):
        status = char + ' ' + msg
        write(status)
        flush()
        write('\x08' * len(status))
        try:
            yield from asyncio.sleep(.1)  # <3>
        except asyncio.CancelledError:  # <4>
            break
    write(' ' * len(status) + '\x08' * len(status))


@asyncio.coroutine
def slow_function():  # <5>
    # pretend waiting a long time for I/O, Non-blocking call!
    yield from asyncio.sleep(3)  # <6>
    return 42


@asyncio.coroutine
def supervisor():  # <7>
    spinner = asyncio.async(spin('thinking!'))  # <8>
    print('spinner object:', spinner)  # <9>
    result = yield from slow_function()  # <10>
    spinner.cancel()  # <11>
    return result


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # <12>
    result = loop.run_until_complete(supervisor())  # <13>
    loop.close()
    print('Answer:', result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

1: Coroutines intended for use with asyncio should be decorated with @asyn
cio.coroutine. This not mandatory, but is highly advisable.

3: Use yield from asyncio.sleep(.1) instead of just time.sleep(.1), to sleep
without blocking the event loop.

4: If asyncio.CancelledError is raised after spin wakes up, it’s because
cancellation was requested, so exit the loop.

5: slow_function is a coroutine, and uses yield from to let the event loop
proceed while this coroutine pretends to do I/O by sleeping.

6: The yield from asyncio.sleep(3) expression handles the control flow to the
main loop, which will resume this coroutine after the sleep delay.

7: supervisor is a coroutine as well, so it can drive slow_function with yield
from.

8: asyncio.async(…) schedules the spin coroutine to run, wrapping it in a Task
object, which is returned immediately

9: Display the Task object. The output looks like Task pending coro= spin()
running at spinner_asyncio.py:12.

10: Drive the slow_function(). When that is done, get the returned value.
Meanwhile, the event loop will continue running because slow_function
ultimately uses yield from asyncio.sleep(3) to hand control back to the main
loop.

11: A Task object can be cancelled; this raises asyncio.CancelledError at the yield
line where the coroutine is currently suspended. The coroutine may catch the
exception and delay or even refuse to cancel.

12: Get a reference to the event loop.

13: Drive the supervisor coroutine to completion; the return value of the coroutine
is the return value of this call.